# Consulta que traiga el primero de cada categoría

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla que contiene múltiples registros de artículos, estos se encuentran separados por categorías y subcategorías, en los cuales quiero obtener el último `id` de cada artículo que pertenezca a esa subcategoría.

```
SELECT *
FROM vcomp_productos_web1
WHERE marca = 'forte'
    AND venta_web = 'si'
GROUP BY categoria
```

Únicamente hago un `GROUP BY`, pero esta consulta me me trae únicamente el primer artículo que tenga esa categoría y necesito traer el último. ¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

Imagen de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como está estructurada tu tabla?

Comment: ¿Qué marca de base de datos es?

Comment: La base de datos es MySQL, solo tiene 1 tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta consulta, supongo que tu `id_producto` es correlativo por lo tanto solo debes de ordenarlos de forma descendente de esta manera te mostrará el último producto ingresado:

```
SELECT *
FROM vcomp_productos_web1
WHERE marca = 'forte'
    AND venta_web = 'si'
GROUP BY categoria
ORDER BY id_producto DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya vi qué está mal, tienes que crear otra tabla con el nombre de subcategorías.

`id`, `subcategoria` y a la tabla categoría le pasas el `id` de cada subcategoría , después haces un `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM subcategoria s
LEFT JOIN categoria c ON s.id = c.id
WHERE c.marca = 'forte'
    AND c.venta_web = 'si'
GROUP BY categoria
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo al menos de dos formas:

### A. Usando `MAX`

```
SELECT MAX(id_producto) id_producto
FROM vcomp_productos_web1
WHERE marca = 'forte'
    AND venta_web = 'si';
```

### B. Usando `LIMIT` combinado con orden DESCendente

```
SELECT id_producto
FROM vcomp_productos_web1
WHERE marca = 'forte'
    AND venta_web = 'si'
ORDER BY id_producto DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! Bro ¿Cómo hago para traer unicamente 3 ultimo de cada categoria?

Comment: @RubxnMC puedes usar la opción **B**, sustituyendo `LIMIT 1` por **`LIMIT 3`**;

Comment: @a-cedano Estoy utilizando esta consulta bro.. SELECT * FROM vcomp_productos_web1 
        WHERE id IN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(id) FROM vcomp_productos_web1 
        WHERE marca = 'FORTE' and venta_web = 'SI' 
        GROUP BY categoria
    ) 
    ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: No entiendo porque el uso de `IN` cuando es la misma tabla. ¿No te funciona como se explica en **A.**  o en **B.**?: **`SELECT * 
FROM vcomp_productos_web1
WHERE marca = 'forte'
    AND venta_web = 'si'
ORDER BY id_producto DESC LIMIT 3;`**

Comment: No cumple realmente la funcion, ya que quiero obtener el ultimo articulo de esa categoria, y son 16 categorias.. La consulta A. me trae solo 1 articulo de una sola categoria y el B. me trae X número de articulos pero de una sola categoria. Cuando en realidad quiero obtener 3 articulos de todas las categorias que existen

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM vcomp_productos_web1 
    WHERE id IN 
(
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM vcomp_productos_web1 
    WHERE marca = 'FORTE' and venta_web = 'SI' 
    GROUP BY categoria
) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Listo, gracias por la colaboración, he logrado obtener la consulta trayendo la información que necesito..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora necesito traer los tres ultimos registros por cada categoria.

Comment: ¿El último `id`  o el último `id_producto`?   O yo no entiendo nada o algo pasa... **si es el `id` lo que quieres, cambiando `id_producto` por `id` debería funcionar**. Y si la tabla es case sensitive, cambiando `si` y `forte` por su equivalente en mayúsculas. O sea: **`SELECT * FROM vcomp_productos_web1 WHERE marca = 'FORTE' AND venta_web = 'SI' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3;`**